# How to write Java code to read 2 queries from excel sheet and compare their DB records?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, db2, database-comparison

Please help with DB comparsion code in java.
I have two queries to execute in same database and compare their records against each other.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mre], sample data, and to clarify what type of comparison you want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run both queries and do the comparison in DB2.
There are variuos ways to do a full comparision of two data sets in SQL.  This is one idea

```
WITH Q1 AS ( put your first query here  )
,    Q2 AS ( put your second query here )
SELECT 'In Q1 not Q2', Q.*
FROM  (SELECT * FROM Q1 MINUS SELECT * FROM Q2) Q
UNION ALL
SELECT 'In Q2 not Q1', Q.*
FROM  (SELECT * FROM Q2 MINUS SELECT * FROM Q1) Q
```